# Get a random port for TCP connection

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, port

I have a client and a server applications. When the client wants to send a file I'm using a TCP connection. when I use a constant port number for the connection it works (The server receives the file).

I want to use a random port so I tried setting the port to 0.

my code is:

```
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = 0;

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
    cout << "failed to bind with errno: "<< errno << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

The binding works but with port 0 instead of a random port as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Afaik, you do not need to call bind on the client side. It will then select the port at random

Comment: How do you expect the client to know what port number to use if server selects one randomly?

Comment: The question is very good Captain. One case is the ISO 15118 standard (electric vehicle communication with the charging station), when the server (station) advertising the TCP connection parameters what the client can obtain by broadcasting an "SDP" (service discovery protocol) request in an UDP packet on the subnet then the server answers the parameters (IP/port) to the client in an UDP packet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, problem solved. I added a call to `getsocketname`

```
if (getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, &len_inet) < 0){
    cout << "failed to get hostname with errno: "<< errno << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`bind()` doesn't update the address structure you pass to it. It's a `const` parameter. If you want to know what port was selected when you specified zero, you must use `getsockname().`

Answer (score 2):

When you have boost available, this looks much more obvious and is portable:

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

int getFreeTCPPort(std::string ipv4)
{
  using namespace boost::asio;

  io_service service;
  ip::tcp::socket socket(service);
  socket.open(ip::tcp::v4());
  socket.bind(ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string(ipv4), 0));
  return socket.local_endpoint().port();
}
```

For sure, it is not answering your question directly, but when the code is self-explanatory, maybe the question is just not coming up.

Comment: Strange, the question is tagged c++ but excepting to cout it is unrelated to c++ - it is a c API used here. Also, it is not related to "linux" it is Berkeley and actually POSIX sockets related. This answer is using a common, portable c++ library available on most Linux systems (at least i know, also embedded) to achieve the goal described in the title "Get a random port for TCP connection" as an additional suggestion but is down voted. There are other answers also not answering the question directly, why this has been down voted?

Comment: Do I need to close the socket before returning from this function?

Answer (score 0):

This small C tool will help you: https://github.com/yegor256/random-tcp-port

Just compile it with `make` and then run `./reserve`

Comment: This small C tool is completely pointless. All you need is a port number of zero when binding.